# Rust - Lifetimes - Understanding Lifetime Error for mutable reference to self

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership, serde

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find a question which matches my question, exactly since I have a couple extra requirements because I have to adhere to some traits that I can't control.

Here is my code. I apologize for the sort of convoluted example, but this was the most I could minimize it as I am trying to implement a custom serialization format using the `serde` library.

```
// Doesn't really matter what this struct contains, it just needs an owning method
struct SideStruct;
impl SideStruct {
    fn something_side<A: TraitA>(&self, aval: A) {
        println!("something sideways :)");
        aval.something_a(42)
    }
}

trait TraitA {
    fn something_a(&mut self, data: u32); // this would be the meat of my logic
}

// Note that this struct has an explicit lifetime
struct MainStruct<'a> {
    refr: &'a mut u32
}

// Note that I implement for a mutable reference to MainStruct
impl<'a> TraitA for &'a mut MainStruct<'a> {
    fn something_a(&mut self, data: u32) {
        // Completely arbitrary, can safely ignore this function body
        *self.refr += data;
        println!("We're finally doing something: {}", self.refr);
    }
}

// Implementing for MainStruct itself
impl<'a> MainStruct<'a> {
    // Note, I can't change the signature for this function because it implements a trait
    fn something_indirect(&mut self, ss: &SideStruct) {
        // here is where the error occurs!
        ss.something_side(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut base_val: u32 = 42;
    let ss = SideStruct {};
    let mut main_val = MainStruct { refr: &mut base_val };
    main_val.something_indirect(&ss);
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:28:27
   |
28 |         ss.something_side(self)
   |                           ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:27:27
   |
27 |     fn something_indirect(&mut self, ss: &SideStruct) {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:28:27
   |
28 |         ss.something_side(self)
   |                           ^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut MainStruct<'a>`
              found `&mut MainStruct<'a>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:26:6
   |
26 | impl<'a> MainStruct<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:28:12
   |
28 |         ss.something_side(self)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `<&mut MainStruct<'a> as TraitA>`
              found `<&mut MainStruct<'_> as TraitA>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
```

I don't know what the compiler means when it states that `note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...`. Does it mean that some constraint forces self to not outlast the method `something_indirect`? That makes no sense. Also the message `so that the expression is assignable` confuses me. `MainStruct` should not be assigned when `something_side` is called on it right? Since I implemented `TraitA` for a mutable reference to `MainStruct`, shouldn't I be able to call `something_side` with a mutable reference to `MainStruct` by passing `self`? Anyways, thanks for the help, and have a great day!

Comment: `&'a mut MainStruct<'a>` is almost always wrong. You should have two different lifetimes here (e.g. `&'a mut MainStruct<'b>`) with the `'b: 'a` constraint to ensure that the struct lives longer than the reference.

Comment: @Jmb The compiler inserts the `'b: 'a` clause automagically. In this case because they're not used this can even be elided lifetimes, i.e. `&'_ mut MainStruct<'_>`.

Comment: It looks like this example is over-reduced: it compiles if you change the `impl<'a> TraitA for &'a mut MainStruct<'a>` to `impl TraitA for &'_ mut MainStruct<'_>`, but I assume there was a reason you put the same lifetime (did the code not compile otherwise?). So we need a less reduced example.

Comment: What do you mean `//Note, I can't change the signature for this function because it implements a trait`? In the posted question at least, there is no issue with changing the lifetimes in the function, and since it's specificly `impl`'d to the `MainStruct` it shouldn't cause issues in the source either (?)

Comment: @Jmb adding that lifetime specifier didn't seem to change anything, and shouldn't the reference always outlast the struct so that the contents of the struct are always valid? Either way, I want the reference in this scenario to outlast the struct.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman there wasn't really a reason I did that specifically except that it was in the example, and I the trait has methods with `self` as parameters instead of `&self` and I didn't want to move `MainStruct` every time I called a method

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that in order to use the method defined, you must borrow the `MainStruct` as mutable with an anonymous lifetime. In the code you wrote, you not only borrow the things within `MainStruct` for `'a`, but also `MainStruct` itself. This is unnecessary since the borrow has an inferred lifetime. You can fix this by removing the `'a` in the trait `impl`

```
impl<'a> TraitA for &mut MainStruct<'a> {
    /*...*/
}
```

This should do the exact same thing, but removes the bug. The bug is trying to tell you that the code you wrote is buggy, because it borrows `MainStruct` using a lifetime in the struct itself.