# Rust lifetime - "does not live long enough" error happens when I create instance

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm writing a toy OS.
I can't fix following lifetime error.

My code fails to compile due to `does not live long enough`

```
error[E0597]: `fb_config` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:37:45
   |
26 | pub extern "sysv64" fn kernel_main (mut fb_config: FrameBufferConfig) -> ! {
   |                                     ------------- has type `FrameBufferConfig<'1>`
...
37 |     let mut pixel_writer = PixelWriter::new(&mut fb_config);
   |                            -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                            |                |
   |                            |                borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                            argument requires that `fb_config` is borrowed for `'1`
...
66 | }
   | - `fb_config` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is a part of my kernel code.
`FrameBufferConfig` has lifetime and was mutable borrowed to `PixelWriter::new()`. `PixelWriter` also has a lifetime and it has the passed `FrameBufferConfig` as a member.

```
// src/main.rs

pub extern "sysv64" fn kernel_main (mut fb_config: FrameBufferConfig) -> ! {
    let mut pixel_writer = PixelWriter::new(&mut fb_config);
    ...
}
```

```
pub struct FrameBufferConfig<'a> {
    pub frame_buffer: FrameBuffer<'a>,   // https://docs.rs/uefi/0.3.2/uefi/proto/console/gop/struct.FrameBuffer.html
...
}
```

```
pub struct PixelWriter<'a> {
    fb_config: &'a mut FrameBufferConfig<'a>,
    pixel_writer: unsafe fn(&mut FrameBuffer, usize, Rgb),
}

impl<'a> PixelWriter<'a> {
    pub fn new(fb_config: &'a mut FrameBufferConfig<'a>) -> Self {
        ...
        PixelWriter {
            fb_config,
            pixel_writer,
        }
    }
```

IMHO, `PixelWriter` should live longer than `FrameBufferCOnfig`.
It looks both `fb_config` (defined at an argument of `kernel_main`) and `PixelWriter` (defined in a `kernel_main`) live and drop until the end of `kernel_main`. So I think `fb_config` lives enough.

To fix it, I tried following 2 approaches.

1. limit `PixelWriter`'s lifetime by block. but it failed. we get the same error.

```
pub extern "sysv64" fn kernel_main (mut fb_config: FrameBufferConfig) -> ! {
    {
        let mut pixel_writer = PixelWriter::new(&mut fb_config);
    }  // PixelWriter dropped?
    ...
}  // fb_config dropped?
```

2. move owner to local value. it passes the compile. but it is redundant.

```
pub extern "sysv64" fn kernel_main (mut fb_config: FrameBufferConfig) -> ! {
    let mut tmp = fb_config;   // move owner here.
    let mut pixel_writer = PixelWriter::new(&mut tmp);
    ...
}
```

Do you have any idea why this error happens? Since I'm a beginner of rust, Do I make a mistake of lifetime?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689224/rust-lifetimes-understanding-lifetime-error-for-mutable-reference-to-self `&'a mut FrameBufferConfig<'a>` is almost always wrong. You should have two different lifetimes here (e.g. `&'a mut FrameBufferConfig<'b>`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
    fb_config: &'a mut FrameBufferConfig<'a>,
```

You have over-constrained this lifetime.

- `&'a mut FrameBufferConfig` means that `'a` specifies how long this `FrameBufferConfig` is borrowed for — the `FrameBufferConfig` will be borrowed for at least `'a`.
- `FrameBufferConfig<'a>` means that `'a` specifies the lifetime of references inside of the `FrameBufferConfig` — so `FrameBufferConfig<'a>` cannot outlive `'a`.

Putting these two together requires the compiler to come to the conclusion that after `PixelWriter::new(&mut tmp)` is executed, the `FrameBufferConfig` is borrowed for the rest of its existence (because if `'a` ends then `FrameBufferConfig<'a>` is no longer valid, but the `FrameBufferConfig` can't stop being borrowed until `'a` ends), and therefore can never be dropped or used in any further way.

In general, when mutable references are involved, you will have more need to use distinct lifetimes (and `&'a mut Foo<'a>` is almost always useless). A simple principle (not optimal, but a place to start) is to either use a separate lifetime for *each* `&mut` involved, or use a separate lifetime for *all* `&mut` involved. (Which way to go depends on the situation.) In your case, we just need to have two lifetimes for the two roles:

```rust
pub struct PixelWriter<'fb, 'gop> {
    fb_config: &'fb mut FrameBufferConfig<'gop>,
    ...
```

(I took the lifetime name `'gop` from the [library documentation](https://docs.rs/uefi/0.16.0/uefi/proto/console/gop/struct.FrameBuffer.html) for consistency.)

It is also possible (depending on your program's needs) that `PixelWriter` should *own* the `fb_config` instead of having a mutable reference to it, i.e.

```rust
pub struct PixelWriter<'gop> {
    fb_config: FrameBufferConfig<'gop>,
    ...
```

But whether that is appropriate or not will depend on what your program's needs are. In particular, if you are going to create multiple `PixelWriter`s sequentially from a single `FrameBufferConfig`, a reference may be appropriate, but if you are going to create only one for each `FrameBufferConfig` then ownership simplifies things.

Comment: I understand. Before dropping `FrameBufferConfig` at the end of `kernel_main`, we need to stop borrowing. To specify that, we set two different lifetimes. If so, why I can pass the compile in approach 2 (use `let mut tmp = fb_config`)? What is the difference? The lifetime of `FrameBufferConfig` is different?

Comment: @ryosky I'm not sure what changed in that second example, and it's hard to be sure without a fully compilable example to test with. But I wouldn't recommend worrying about it — just avoid `&'a mut T<'a>` entirely.